# Unknown error in ASP.NET MVC project.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Before:**

I have the following code in my MVC controller action. It works well in the development machine running VS2012 but fails to save in the production environment in IIS.
What could be the problem? I have stepped through in code but no errors at all. In production it does not show any error in e.Message or dbEx.Message either. Thanks for the assistance.

**After**

I have an MVC action which is supposed to save a file together with the rest of the information.

The code works fine on my developer machine, but when I run it on the production server the file is not saved. I get no error at all in my controller.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Tried to log the exceptions
2. I can see the file being posted in Chrome Developer Tools
3. I've checked file permissions in the target folder

The code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateRecipe(MenuDto model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (Session["username"] == null || Session["jobtitle"] == null)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Sorry your session has timed out or you have not logged in. Please log-in.";
            return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Home");
        }
        try
        {

            var cl = new CategoryBL();
        ViewBag.ListCategories = new SelectList(new List<Category>(){ new Category() { CatName = "--Select Category--"}}.Concat(cl.RetrieveAll()),
            "CatName", "CatName"); 

            RecipeBL bl = new RecipeBL();
             model.Recipes = bl.RetrieveAll();
            if (file == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Msg = "Please select a picture for this recipe";
                return View(model);
            } 

            string path = "";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/pictures/Recipes"), pic);

                    // file is uploaded
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    model.Image = @"\pictures\Recipes\" + file.FileName;
                }


                var item = new Recipe()
                {
                    RecipeCode = model.RecipeCode,
                    RecipeMethod = model.RecipeMethod,
                    RecipeName = model.RecipeName, 
                    SellingPrice = model.SellingPrice,
                    Image = model.Image,
                    SubCategory = model.SubCategory
                };
                bl.Create(item, Session["username"].ToString());

            }
            ViewBag.Msg = "Recipe was successfully registered.";
            model.Recipes = bl.RetrieveAll();
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Msg = "Recipe registration failed." + dbEx.Message;
            return View(model);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Msg = "Recipe registration failed." + e.Message;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 as you don't explain the problem and just expects us to fix it. What have you tried to solve it? How do you reproduce it?

Comment: Everything I put in there is exactly how it happened. How am I supposed to explain a problem I do not know? It was because I tried to solve it and could not that I put it up on StackOverflow. I am not new here so I know the rules. The problem is simple-The code snippet above works well and commits the data in MenuDto model into the database when I run in VS 2012. No errors at all even with a break point. Yet when I deploy it on IIS it does not commit to the database and it is not because it was not connected to db because i had logged in successfully and connection string in web config is ok

Comment: `but fails to save` is a very wide description. What is not saved? Do it work in some cases? Are the file included in the post or is it missing in the production environment? Have you checked file permissions? Do the folder exist? That's why you get a -1. Show some effort.

Comment: @jgauffin Thanks for the help, even though you sounded a bit harsh back there. I did make some effort probably I am not communicating in a way you would understand. The error finally showed however,it was a file access denied error. The folder was there on the production machine and the file was included in the post. So I granted file/folder access permissions on the inetpub folder to the logged in user and that was it.

Comment: I'm not trying to sound harsh. But there are a lot of questions with little or no description. By reading those it's hard to find effort. A few paragraphs showing what you have tried displays that much better. It's nothing personal.

Comment: Read my edit to see what I mean. That's some effort in helping us understand that you've really tried by yourself.

Comment: I think I get it now. I am trying out one of your tools: https://onetrueerror.com/. I think its interesting, jgauffin and would have helped in my code too especially after deploying to IIS since the error escaped my Development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the error showed up. It was a fie access denied error - Uploading of the file to C:\users\inetpub….\picturefolder\ failed. Access denied. I realized that the error was hidden but I do not know why. It eventually showed itself today.

Pretty simple solution was to change security/folder permission settings on the folder for the logged in user. I right clicked on the inetpub parent folder and selected properties in context menu then selected security tab. When I clicked on the logged in user, I noticed that NOT ALL the boxes in the Permission window is checked under Allow. So I selected ALL (write, etc), then Applied. I was now good to go. I attempted the operation to save the uploaded image file and it worked as it should. :)

Comment: It's enough with the change permission.